# Does API JARs are required at runtime?

Tags: java, dependency-management

In my one of the project I am using slf4j-simple and simple-java-mail with some other dependencies. When I see `Gradle runtimeClasspath` (also added screenshot below) in IntelliJ then I see that slf4j-api, jakarta-mail-api and jakarta-activation-api is also part of runtime along with it's actual implementation JARs like slf4j-simple, jakarta-mail and jakarta-activation respectively. It is also seen that slf4j-simple also delivers slf4j-api even though that is a compile time dependency.

[image]

Is it safe to remove all API JARs manually by mentioning `exclusion` in my project's build.gradle file? Can we consider that always any API jar should not be part of runtime ?

Can anyone also give specification about this for each of above mentioned libraries ?

Comment: If the libraries are built "correctly", then the implementation JARs will not contain the API classes, thus the API JARs are still required at run-time.

Comment: @Slaw That means do you mean that here slf4j and jakarta-mail/activation libraries are not built correctly?

Comment: @Slaw because I have observed and also read on web that jakarta-mail and jakarta-activation implementation JARs also has API classes. And about slf4j-simple they say if it is in your class path then no need to have it's API until you do not have any other logging mechanism than slf4j

Comment: `slf4j-api` is a transitive dependency of `slf4j-simple`, so yes, you can simply declare a dependency on the latter only, and the former will be implicitly pulled in. However, the `slf4j-api` classes are not contained in the `slf4j-simple` JAR. And those classes are needed at run-time, so you need the `slf4j-api` JAR on the run-time class-path/module-path. I don't know for sure how Jakarta Mail is organized, but I'd suspect something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to do it, not all implementation packages contain APIs too. If you **exclude** such dependency, your will encounter class-loader errors on runtime.

Besides try to have `implementation` dependency on APIs and `runtimeOnly` dependency on implementations. This way the compiler enforces you just using APIs and not implementations (which are usually lead to vendor-lock-in and version-lock-ins).

Comment: Got it, but here in my case in build.gradle file I have only specified simple-java-mail and smime-module due to which it's dependent JARs are also coming. In such cases what should I do ? As marked in screenshot from simple-java-mail, jakarta-mail (implementation) is coming along with jakarta-activation (implementation) but from bcjmail it's API JARs are also residing in my runtime class path, which is sort off conflicting as both jakarta-mail and jakarta-activation implementation and API jars have same classes.